# Toggle buttons state not changing

Tags: android, togglebutton

Sorry for the nOOb 'ness but I'm stuck on what I thought was a simple piece of code.

When 2 toggle buttons state is changed to On, wait a few seconds and toggle their state to off. Both buttons have textOn="On" and textOff="Off". The following code is placed in OnClickListeners for both tbToggle1 and tbToggle2.

```
  tbToggle1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tbToggle1.isChecked() & tbToggle2.isChecked()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                tbToggle1.setChecked(false);
                tbToggle2.setChecked(false);
            }
  });
```

After pressing tbToggle1 (it changes to "On") and then pressing tbToggle2- both buttons change their state to "Off" after 3 seconds. I need tbToggle2 to change to "On" for the 3 seconds before changing to "Off".

Is it a UI thread issue or something? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Thread.sleep` on the UI thread which is never a good idea.

Try this:

```
tbToggle1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (tbToggle1.isChecked() & tbToggle2.isChecked()) {
            tbTogggle1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tbToggle1.setChecked(false);
                    tbToggle2.setChecked(false);
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
});
```